# Reverse gravity on node only

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, skphysicsbody

I would like to reverse the gravity on a single node, but I can't find any property to do that.

I saw that you can change the gravity of the world:

```
self.physicsWorld.gravity = CGVector(dx: 0, dy: 1)
```

But it doesn't exist for a node:

```
// I would like do this
node.physicsBody.gravity = CGVector(dx: 0, dy: 1)
```

How can I do this?

Thanks

Comment: Gravity affects all nodes in the scene (unless specified otherwise). There is only one direction at any one time. You can set the veolocity of a node so that it it goes against the gravity direction, but it cant slow and come to a stop, or bounce to a stop, without you coming up with functions to deal with it. Is it possible you can put more detail in what you are trying to achieve with this? Whats the idea behind it? Maybe then someone can suggest a route for you to go down.

Comment: To tell you more concretely what I want to do, I have several balls on my scene (each ball is a node) and the user would have the possibility to reverse the gravity of a ball by clicking on it. Instead of falling, the node would have to fly away from the world (like gravity). The problem is that I want to be able to both keep gravity on my nodes and reverse gravity on some of them.

Comment: If your outcome is for the ball to just fly away and not come back, you could apply a strong impulse to it when someone touches it, then once its off the screen remove the node.

Comment: See this question and answer from a few days ago.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66699912/custom-gravity-for-single-node-in-spritekit